# Why don't we rotate tyres but you rotate tires?

Tags: tires, wear

Is planning a regular rotation of new tyres over their lifespan a good or bad plan?

From many posts I've seen here and elsewhere on the web, motorists in the USA seem to see rotating tires as a task which ought to be undertaken at regular intervals.  By rotating tires, I mean moving their position on the vehicle, so moving them from the front to rear axle for example.

In the UK, we seldom do this.  Indeed one of the biggest tyre fitters in the country actually advises against the practice (see link [here](https://www.kwik-fit.com/tyres/information/tyre-rotation))

I've just fitted a set of four tyres to our 2012 VW Golf and wondered if it is worth rotating them over the life of the tyres.  Is there any advice that is clearly for or against the practice and are there any studies which back this up?

Comment: I know that some fitting stations in the UK won't rotate tyres at all. 

"For improved handling and stability it is now recommended that the ‘best’ tyres should always be fitted at the rear of the vehicle. This is irrespective of whether the car is front or rear wheel drive."
I find this very interesting from Kwik Fit - if the car is FWD, then the most grippy tyres should go on the front? Unless they define 'best' as the most reliable, the tyres least likely to have a blow out.

Comment: Interestingly, the manufacturer of the tyres I've had fitted do recommend, even in the EU, tyre rotation; https://www.goodyear.eu/en_gb/consumer/learn/rotating-your-tires.html

Comment: It is a fair point that if you have *already failed to rotate* tires resulting in significantly different wear then you do not want to rotate them such that the more worn tires are in the rear.  Of course the point of regular rotation is to avoid this situation.

Comment: Note also the *real reason* for keeping the "best" on the rear is not about likelihood of blowout. It is about having better grip (especially in the wet) at the rear. This is regardless of front/rear drive. The fact that web site completely missed this is baffling.

Comment: @MRichards This is complete nonsense.  Uneven grip between the front and rear is always bad - the most extreme example of this is fitting winter tires only to the rear (or front) of a vehicle, whether FWD, AWD, or RWD - it doesn't matter.  Handling becomes less predictable in all cases.

Comment: I would follow the tire manufacturers recommendations. Note that the Kwik-Fit article doesn't cite a single tire manufacturer. None of their recommendations make sense especially the unsubstantiated assertion that partly worn tires are more likely to puncture. Do they sell "upgraded, anti-skid tire filling", too?

Comment: What do you consider the difference between a tyre and a tire? Is a tire a tired tyre?

Comment: The difference appears to be in the results google returned when looking for source material.  Lots of articles stating "tires should be rotated" and many others at .co.uk sites stating "tyres should not be rotated".

Comment: With reference to the Kwik Fit guidance, I wonder, as they suggest don't rotate and fit the best on the rear.  When you inevitably return to buy a pair to replace the fronts, do they fit those on the rear and rotate the ones previously on the rear to the front of the car?  This, surely, is a form of tyre rotation?

Comment: @ J... This is not true. A lot of sports-cars even have bigger tyres on the rear axel => more grip at the back. Normal modern cars are mostly designed to sightly understeer which has shown to be the more *predictable* reaction to most drivers., and the one easier to handle instinctively.

Comment: @Mast A tyre is a tire that is located in the U.K. while a tire is a tyre that is located in the U.S.

Comment: I'm in the US and if I buy 2 tires my local shop insists on putting them on the rear. They also recommend regular rotation. I recently had to replace a single damaged tire and they were happy to install it on the front, though.

Comment: Also, +1 simply for the excellent title!

Comment: I don't know how up-to-date my info is, but isn't tyre life another major factor? I remember US adverts for 100,000 mile tyres, and awful tyre squeal on cornering suggesting rock-hard rubber, but the UK tends to have softer rubber and 20,000 mile lifetimes.

Comment: @KenY-N That difference in rubber hardness is probably more about differences in the climatic conditions the tires are designed to work in, and possibly expected surface conditions, than about differences between the countries per se. The difference in expected life would then be a consequence of this.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling This was in LA and Las Vegas, so I suppose the compound couldn't be too soft, but I would think companies could as easily make a 20,000 mile tyre for desert conditions? I processed that at the time  as the average US consumer being more interested in price rather than performance. Hmm, I think I have a new question here, so I'll stop speculating in the comments.

Comment: Is "we" in the title the UK and "you" the US?  I'm from neither, and the title is utterly confusing.

Comment: @Phil presumably you’ve heard the tomato tomato song?  It’s kind of a tribute to that.

Comment: Where does all of the force go when you brake? It isn't in one place, it is the front at least a little. The car wants to keep going forward by the laws of physics and your brakes are saying no through friction. Rotation should keep wear and tear more even.

Comment: @AndrewScottEvans on a Golf (which this is), 85% of braking is done with the front wheels.  That’s according to research done by Tim Styles, founder of TSR Performance.

Comment: At first I thought this to be from ELL or ELU.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

tl dr: Kwik Fit is full of crap. It's good to rotate tyres (and tires, too :o).

The entire idea of rotating tires is to keep the wear relatively similar (or even), front to rear. If rotation is done at the specified intervals, the only time you'll have a *weaker tire* of appreciable wear is when it's time to replace all four.

I don't know what the end goal of [Kwik Fit](https://www.kwik-fit.com/home) is, but there are several things they state on their website which are VERY disturbing to me having to do with tire (tyre) rotation. Here is what I'm talking about.

**Note:** I'm taking quotes from the page you linked.

> - Partly worn tyres are more likely to experience punctures – particularly in wet weather conditions.

What does wet weather have to do with whether a tire is punctured or not? Absolutely nothing, as far as I can tell. Road hazards will flatten a tire just as quickly in dry weather as it will in wet.

> - Front tyre deflation will create an under-steer effect which is easier to control than over-steer (the effect produced by a rear tyre deflation)

Understeer by definition is: "(with automobiles) having a tendency to turn less sharply than is intended". Does anyone believe if you have a sudden tire deflation on the front end you are going to be able to turn the vehicle more sharply than if you lose it on the back end? I certainly don't.

> - In the unlikely event that a tyre deflates suddenly, then it is easier to control the vehicle if this occurs at the front of the vehicle. For improved handling and stability it is now recommended that the ‘best’ tyres should always be fitted at the rear of the vehicle. This is irrespective of whether the car is front or rear wheel drive.

~70% of the braking power and most all of the steering power is controlled from the front end of the vehicle. If you suddenly lose air pressure in a front tire, you've now lost a major portion of both, which means you've lost a major amount of control of the vehicle. This is *especially true* if you are traveling down the motorway at 70mph (which I believe is the typical posted speed on the M1, right?). By having a blowout on the rear of the vehicle, you maintain almost all of your braking power and lose very little of your turning power (rear might want to drift some). If you lose a front tire, it will drag the car in the direction of the lost tire. If the pull is great enough, it can most likely cause an accident, either through dragging the car into other traffic or causing the driver to lose control and creating a single car accident.

It seems to me this tyre company has an agenda. One in which they want their patrons to wear out their tires faster, so they'll come back and buy more tires. Having the weaker tire on the rear of the vehicle is not going to create as big of an issue as having it on the front.

Other things they state there on the website are accurate. You don't rotate tires on a vehicle where the front and rear are different sizes (like you'd see on some sport vehicles). I have never seen a car which has a specification for asymmetric tread pattern at one end of the vehicle and symmetrical at the other, but I guess there could be. In this case, you don't want to rotate the tires, either.

Comment: Very true - and consider KwikFit's marketing slogan "*You can't get quicker than a KwikFit fitter*".  Any half decent fitter would take the time to do it properly.

Comment: Yep - While a very large and popular chain KwikFit have a somewhat *dubious* [reputation](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/1j7733DfDM3jcXJfWGPM49P/inside-kwik-fit), personally I would be taking any "advice" from them with a whole sackful of salt.

Comment: Also, at least that's how I learned it, if the tires do not have a specified rotation-direction, you should even switch them diagonally.

Comment: @JanNash - I've only ever considered radial ply tires to go front to rear, as once they have been ran a certain way, they like to stay in that direction. If you reverse the direction of the tire, it can cause premature wear. Bias ply tires never had this issue and you could rotate them crisscross and what have you. You won't gain much by crisscrossing them anyway, as it's the front v. back where all the wear difference occurs.

Comment: Agreed, I should have been more clear on that.
I guess that some of the wear difference might also occur left vs. right, for example if you're always driving alone or always taking a round trip in the same direction. But I also guess that you can safely ignore that as it shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: It's true that most braking power comes from the front wheels. However, rear wheel traction is very important to vehicle stability under braking. In a braking condition, losing traction to the front wheels results in decreased braking distance and reduced ability to steer. Losing traction to the rear wheels causes the vehicle to spin out. Both are undesirable, but usually spinning out is worse.

Comment: I have no idea if it applies to motor vehicle tires, but in my experience bicycle tires are indeed more likely to go flat on wet roads. As I understand it the water sticks debris to the tire, which then works it's way into the same spot in the rubber with every rotation.

Comment: Joined just to comment on understeer vs oversteer. On the one occasion that I got my new tyres put on the front rather than the rear I nearly had an accident driving home from the garage, due to the front tyres having far more grip than the rear tyres. A *little* understeer is much easier to control than a *little* oversteer: if you have a little understeer you can brake and then make the corner, if you have a little oversteer you're on the limit of a spin.

Comment: Came here to disagree about understeer vs oversteer as stated by Kwiksh... I mean Kwikfit. Understeer is "being unable to steer". Oversteer is "amplified steering". I've been in several situations with both, and I tell you, in every case, it's far safer to experience oversteer than understeer, because you can apply countersteer correction. With understeer, all you can do is wait it out or crash. I learnt to drive in RWD and FWD cars 30 years ago, and I've driven a broad mix of FWD, RWD, 4WD and AWD cars, trucks, and vans since.

Comment: @Taegost Nobody here is repeating the old myth that new tires should go on the front. https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/29079/if-only-replacing-two-tires-should-they-go-on-the-front-or-back

Comment: What @Rich said. Understeer (loss of steering) is dead scary, about the worst possible thing that can happen to your equipment while driving. Oversteer is no big deal. At worst you end up in a much-less-deadly sort of crash. At best you know how to control it and escape with no damage.

Comment: @stannius that sounds somewhat plausible, however I have had much more tyres do flat in _dry_ conditions, although I cycle a lot on wet roads (living in notoriously rainy Cologne). Also, I doubt the mechanism would work on a car going at more than 60 km/h – the centrifugal force safely prohibits anything from sticking more than a few rotations.

Comment: @R. I agree, however what they're saying probably does hold some truth for inexperienced drivers: those may react in wild panic, turn the steering wheel erratically around and step on the brake. With an oversteering car, this is guaranteed to spin the car out, with an understeering car it can with some luck run you only in shallow angle against the traffic barrier.

Comment: reasonably good answer, but i downvoted due to your invalid syllogism. if front tire deflation causes understeer, and understeer is the reduced ability to turn sharply, then it does *not* logically follow that front tire deflation would increase your ability to turn sharply.

Comment: @jamesturner - You misread what I wrote ... I said if you lose a tire on the front end it makes it harder to steer the vehicle ... I stated it as a rhetorical question. Please reread.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Or across the median into a head-on collision with an 18-wheeler.

Comment: @R.. in Europe there aren't many 18-wheelers, and the median on motorways is almost always a rigid barrier. (But of course you're right, understeering _is_ always highly dangerous, just for bad drivers probably not quite as dangerous as oversteering.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Here the "median" is often a patch of grass or just a double yellow line...

Comment: I read what you wrote the same way as @jamesturner. Your 'rhetorical question' doesn't make sense, and doesn't contradict the immediately prior quotation. Either you're agreeing with it, which is futile, or disagreeing with it, in which case you're wrong.

Comment: @EJP - Then I think you've completely missed the point. If the front tire is flat, the vehicle would be harder to steer because you have less control (one tire v. two tires). Nothing wrong with that statement and I stand by it. I'm ***definitely*** disagreeing with Kwik Fit's statement because they are wrong. If you want to disagree with me, that's your prerogative.

Comment: KwikRip, I wouldn't trust to look after a bicycle let alone my car. However, they're half right about rear tyre deflation but they've fudged the answer. If you have a blow out on the front of the car, the car is harder to turn but will generally keep in a straight line. If you have a blowout on the rear, the car is liable to be thrown to the side and become unstable. I've seen a video of a cop car in the UK suffer a rear tyre blow out on the motorway, it's not pretty.

Comment: Some car manufacturers advise AGAINST rotating your tyres. They say that the marginal gains outweigh the benefits and that the sudden change in tyre performance is more dangerous than a slow degradation.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 i think the confusion here might be that you interpret "easier to control" as "able to turn more sharply". that is not what kwik fit is saying.  they are suggesting that compensating for understeer simply requires turning the steering wheel further than normal, whereas compensating for oversteer can require advanced and counter-intuitive techniques such as counter-steering. from a technical perspective, understeer is "dynamically stable" unlike oversteer which is "dynamically unstable" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Understeer_and_oversteer#Limit_conditions

Comment: You highlight three things that KwikFit say that you describe as "very disturbing". But the second one, you seem to be saying that the statement is completely obviously true. So what's disturbing?

Comment: The chance of puncture is increased in the wet (as least for some tyres) as shown starkly in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbnUqTF04v4).

Comment: @jamesturner: You are dangerously (and intentionally?) misinterpreting "dynamic stability". In an understeer condition you can't compensate by turning the wheel farther. The article you linked clearly says "the vehicle cannot increase lateral acceleration".

Comment: @JanNash About rotating diagonally, see my question [Is it acceptable to move tires between sides of a car? (left to right / right to left)](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/49382/7356)

Comment: @R I suppose from a pure physics point of view, it is more stable: forces keep operating on the car in the same way until you crash (or don't). With oversteer, you have to constantly re-evaluate the forces acting on the car, and it is intuitive to over-correct (more-so than with understeer) because a dynamic situation is a bit scarier. Controlling it effectively requires a minimum amount of skill, which is not shared by all drivers. Having said that, I've yet to be in a real-life situation where either was bad enough to be dangerous.

Comment: @R.. i assure you i am not intentionally misinterpreting anything. in fact, i have tried hard to see how anyone could interpret these sources differently. it seems clear to me that you can compensate for understeer by turning the wheel further (a natural instinct) until you reach the limit condition, at which point you have reached "dynamic stability".  both the initial condition and the limit condition of understeer are easier to control than oversteer for the untrained driver. you seem to be misinterpreting (unintentionally) the limit condition of understeer as the definition of understeer.

Comment: While I tend to agree that oversteer is preferable, this is almost definitely not the case for inexperienced drivers. The number of people that crash their new (RWD, oversteer-prone) sports cars is rather telling

Comment: I think the understeer/oversteer issue is largely irrelevant. There's a huge difference in the remaining control with the loss of a front tire versus a rear tire.

Comment: It would be great to see citations/objective sources. The premise of the question is that there are conflicting recommendations, and the answers reflect that. Coming from other SE sites, I'm surprised that the highest voted answer seems to be entirely opinion based, with no attempt to find an objective source. Reading through the answers I see claims of shady motives by tyre companies to not rotate, shady motives by service stations to rotate often, contradicting recommendations in manuals (BMW - no rotate, Subaru - rotate), lots of anecdotes, and I am less sure than I was a week ago.

Comment: @Gregor - If you boil this answer down, **the second para is the money shot**. I tried to put the bottom line up front (just beyond the tl dr). While there is some opinion in this answer, most of what I put on here is either common sense or is documented elsewhere on this site. Some of the answer requires the reader to believe what I'm saying as I do have some acumen in this arena. You give BMW/Subaru as examples, yet these are completely different cars. BMW most likely has different size tires front to rear, while the Subaru AWD ***MUST*** remain equal on both ends or you blow up the transfer

Comment: Yes - 70 is the maximum speed in the UK (faster than the US?) and is the speed on many roads most roads with >= 2 lanes per direction that are not through a residential area. This includes Motorways and many major A roads.

Comment: @Rich, I wholeheartedly disagree with you. Having had cars with a tendency to understeer and oversteer, oversteer is more fun but I'd much rather have understeer, especially in a blowout situation. It's much simpler to control understeer and it's not a developing situation. If you don't get oversteer under control fast enough it can be too late very quickly. Understeer keeps doing the same thing until you deal with it.

Comment: @jamesturner - My most memorable understeer situation was in fog, wet road, with an "invisible" stopped line of traffic ahead of me at a particularly thick fogbank. Going too fast for the conditions, so I braked as soon as I could, and the front wheels locked up. Thus, despite turning the wheel to steer into the neighbouring lane, I continued straight (understeer). When I lifted my foot about 12' from the nearest car, front wheels bit, & immediately steered me **suddenly** and **unpredictably**. If I hadn't been ready, I'd've been fighting oversteer then. Understeer is dangerous!

Comment: @Separatrix Wrong. Understeer keeps doing the same thing until you regain traction, which you _cannot_ control, and which may then lead to sudden oversteer. See my previous comment to jamesturner.

Comment: @Rich, what you describe there is doing everything wrong with a case of lockup, not understeer.

Answer (score 50):

Just thought it was an interesting topic, so googled around a bit for actual sources.

First of all, some (or maybe all) BMW's actively recommend [NOT rotating tyres](https://www.cartalk.com/content/owners-manual-my-bmw-i-says). Cartalk covered this in one of their shows, and here are the most notable quotes:

> TOM: We've always felt that tire rotation is of marginal value in terms of saving you money. Why? Because the cost of tire rotation roughly equals the amount you'd save by extending your tire life.
>
> RAY: You can see why mechanics like it. Not only is it an easy few bucks for us, but it also gets your car into the shop again so we can sell you other services — like engine flushes and fuzzy-dice reupholstering!

So that might explain the reason for its popularity in the USA.

Regarding BMW they say

> TOM: BMW cites safety because the front and rear tires develop different wear patterns. And for at least a little while — until the wear evens out, which is the point of tire rotation — you might have slightly inferior handling with newly rotated tires.

They argue to only do it if the car is already having other maintance which requires taking the wheels off. Unlike BMW they believe that rotating tyres is a good thing, just not worth the money or trouble by itself:

> TOM: So, our feeling has always been that if the tire rotation is free, do it. In other words, if you're having your brakes checked, and the wheels are already off the car and your mechanic is nice enough to put them back on different wheels for nothing, then do it. That's what we do for our customers.

and

> TOM: Still, we see nothing wrong with rotating your tires. No harm will be done, in our opinion. But if you're paying your BMW mechanic $125 an hour to move your tires around (and eight bucks a wheel for rebalancing, too), it's very unlikely you'll save any money in the long run, Larry.

Sadly I wasn't able to find any actual studies. Maybe it's worth posting on skeptics.SE, there are a lot of experts there when it comes to finding (obscure) studies. Still I feel like this source draws from a bit more authority than anything else I could find.

Comment: Great points, though here in the States, free rotation/balancing comes with the purchase of the tire (at most reputable places ... or is a minimal charge). This sort of makes their point moot about the charge. Secondly, most enthusiasts might prefer to rotate their tires themselves. It saves a lot of time/planning to do so. Waiting somewhere for them to do this is a real PITB.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 As you can see from my reputation I am far from a car enthousiast, but could it be that car mechanics see it as a way for people to get a car into their shop? Just like in the Netherlands (country I lived in for years) a lot of shops offer dirt cheap legally required car checkups, in the hope to sell you other services.

Comment: They do the same here in the States, no doubt. I'm not disagreeing with what you've stated, just pointing out about the cost of rotations, is all.

Comment: Yeah, tire rotation can be good, but it is almost never worth the cost of having someone do it.

Comment: This is the right answer. Tire rotation is something you can do for free at a lot of shops or even for free in your own driveway. You do end up with a more balanced wear and can avoid the awkward stage where you only need to replace 2 tires at a time.

Comment: @caesay "Free in your own driveway" - only if you value your time at $0

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the cost saving argument. If your car wears rear tyres at rate "1 pair per year"  and front tyres at rate "2 pairs per year", then over the course of two years you'll have to purchase 6 pairs of new tyres whether you rotate them or not. Not rotating, you replace the fronts every 6 months and rears every 12. Rotating, you replace on the following schedule: Fronts@7.5months, Rears@9, R@15, F@16.5, F@24 and R@24. Rotating causes more time/money wasting because your car visits the shop 8 times, vs not rotating only 4 times

Comment: @caesay You make the opposite point as the answer, yet you claim it is correct. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: If this is true, then conversely, it would seem tire sellers would *not* like tire rotation, if replacing your tires means you pay them more often instead of the mechanic. I suppose environmentalists might like tire rotation if it means producing and throwing away fewer tires; that could actually have something to do with its popularity.

Comment: @jpmc26 But rotation _doesn't_ mean you throw away fewer tyres. See [Caius Jard's comment](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/49367/why-dont-we-rotate-tyres-but-you-rotate-tires#comment85691_49375). If you don't rotate, and just replace the front and rear tyres separately as they wear, you go through exactly the same number of tyres. You're still accumulating the same total amount of wear to your tyres regardless of how they're arranged, so rearranging them can't affect the number of tyres that need to be replaced in the long term.

Comment: @DavidMulder So, there's no safety aspect at all to this? This is entirely about saving money?

Comment: @qntm Question is whether you believe car manufacturers like BMW. They claim that it would be dangerous to rotate tyres, whilst Tom & Ray are arguing that it's probably not.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Don't tires have uneven wear on the *sides* (left and right), though?

Answer (score 12):

You always fit the best tires on the rear.  *Why?* They don't motor*, don't steer and barely brake - why can't rear wheels just be *casters*?

### The rear tires are your *rudder*

They keep your car from spinning out.   To be technical, they provide stability in *yaw*, and they don't steer, so *vertical stabilizer* is more correct. Ever seen those on the *front* of an airplane?  Nope, and for good reason!

[image] [src](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8602/can-a-plane-fly-without-the-vertical-stabilizer)

Driving a curve (and some other things) put sideways force on every tire.  Here's the key question: In poor traction, **will your front or rear tires break away first?**

If your front tires break first, your car will seek to go in a straight line.  (understeer). As it gets near breakaway, you'll notice - the steering will be less responsive.  If you are properly trained, you will "turn into the skid" (align the steer wheels with the direction you are actually going).  Why? Wheels have best *sideways* traction when rolling straight - when cocked at an angle, traction is much worse. By aligning wheels with the skid, you get maximum traction and soon recover control.   (and of course this will correct the rear problem too.)

If your rear tires break first, there is *nothing you can do about it*. **You can't steer your rear wheels into the skid**.  The increasing angle makes traction even worse - a vicious cycle, which is why a spin-out is hard to stop! I've spun 360 on a tight cloverleaf freeway on-ramp going 25 mph in simple rain.  That's when I grokked the "rudder" thing, and put my best tires on the rear.

**Best tires go on the rear because you want the rear to break away *last*.**

### The rudder is their main thing

Of course they support the weight of the car, but in front engine cars, 60% of your weight is on the front.  When you brake hard, it shifts the weight even more forward!  So most of the braking is done by the front.

And the vast majority of cars are front-drive, so the rear wheels don't even provide power. They might as well be casters, *except for the rudder thing!*

### Sideload, steering and power/braking all tax the same traction

A tire has a finite amount of traction.  Sideload, steering, and power/braking all "dip out of that same pool" of traction.  If all of them together add up to more traction than available, the wheel must slip!

On the **front wheels**, that's much more manageable - because you control power (on a front drive car), braking and steering. You can back off any of those and put that traction back in the pool for something else to use.   You can't do that with the rears, unless it's a rear-drive car and you can lift off the throttle.

In fact, in a rear-drive car, if you punch the throttle hard, you can use up all the traction and cause sideslip.  It's *very* easy to over-do it and spin out entirely... but done right, it is [drifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drifting_(motorsport)) or a [bootlegger's turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootleg_turn), and swings the rear around right where you want it.

---

* Presuming FWD cars, which are the vast majority of cars on the road today.  I cover RWD cars at length in the non-TLDR section, and frankly, RWD drivers tend to be knowledgeable and understand their car is an exception, and don't need this explained to them.

Comment: Have you ever been in an airplane with a pilot who turns the rudder the wrong way in a turn? (Your local flying school or flying club might let you experience it with an instructor.) Hint: you're in for *quite a sideways ride*. And an airplane in flight obviously doesn't have to deal with surface traction, which would only complicate things.

Comment: "They don't motor"??? Every car I have owned since in the last 25 years has had power through the rear wheels - so I think your opening line isn't quite right. You could edit to say that you are talking about FWD cars only...

Comment: If the rear tyres lose traction there is plenty you can do about it.  Arm-fulls of opposite lock and a reasonable prod of the throttle are usually all that's needed to snap the car back to where you intended it to do.  If you're understeering at speed in a FWD vehicle above a certain speed there isn't really much you can do other than lift off, tighten your line and hope for the best.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I cover that in depth in the non-TLDR section.  You are also enough of an enthusiast, and competent enough, to recognize that your car is unusual and an exception.   However, I went ahead and put the asterisk *in* the TLDR section.

Comment: Have an upvote from me @Harper - the rest of your post was spot on anyway. It was just that one minor bit got me :-)

Comment: @SteveMatthews Sure... racing conditions where you're rounded that curve hundreds of times, or a skilled driver experienced at driving his sporty vehicle **at the margins** on basically good pavement: in both conditions you intentionally dip your toe *just* beyond margins. Sport drivers don't need answers like mine, so I don't clutter the answer with stuff only for them. OP is about ordinary folk doing ordinary driving in bad conditions where it's a surprise and suddenly way beyond margins  (and the GTR stays in the barn!)

Comment: Nobody appears to have considered the potential affect on braking distance, surely that is an important factor to consider?

Comment: @MikeT Good point, but having your rear brakes lock up is another way to lose your rudder.  Now your front is outbraking your rear, the rear has lost its rudder (they're casters) and that rear is gonna want to come around.

Comment: The rudder is a terrible analogy, since the rudder is used to turn an aeroplane or boat. Rear tyres are more like the *keel* on a boat, or a better comparison would be the **lee boards** on scows.

Comment: @Rich I know, but I'm going for an instantly recognizable layman's term for *vertical stabilizer*, the tall vertical wing which has the rudder typically on its aft surface, except on some jets e.g. Fighters where the whole thing moves). Regardless, when the rudder is set/trimmed straight, its job is indeed to resist yaw.

Answer (score 7):

Check with the tyre manufacturer. If anyone would know, it'd be them - not a shop full of work experience kids.

When rotating tyres, move the fronts to the back, and the backs to the front on the same side. Do NOT cross-rotate them; that can cause premature wear.

Why is the UK different? Because of consumer expectations driven by marketing. In the UK, I had a car (Vauxhall Astra 2001) which had 20,000 mile oil change intervals (http://oil-change.info/vauxhall-astra-g-engine-oil-capacity/). In the US, 3,000 mile intervals are the generally accepted standard.

Comment: Cross rotation is fine with symmetric tread.  The only time you do a front-back rotate is with directional tires.

Comment: Another major difference between the UK and most of the US is the climate. Both the annual temperature range, and the average temperature, are much less extreme in the UK. That also affects oil change intervals, of course - 18,000 miles is fairly typical. My own car (European designed) only burns half a liter of oil between 18,000 changes after 100,000 miles, and the oil looks just as clean after 18,000 as it did after 1,000. UK/US oil specifications may also be different - you might not want to run a car in hot desert conditions on 0W-30 oil, but the UK doesn't have any hot deserts!

Comment: 3,000 miles between oil changes? This is not the 1980s. Most newer vehicles have oil monitoring and they tell you, based on driving conditions, when they need an oil change. My car just informed me this past week it needs one, around 7,000 miles since its last oil change. Before that, the interval was 10,000 miles.

Comment: @alephzero I'm running a car in the hot desert on 0W-20.  That's what the manual says.  Synthetic, 10,000 miles, natural, 5,000 miles.  The synthetic isn't twice the price and it also saves the time of having it done.

Comment: No one recommends 3,000 mile oil changes except for the places trying to sell them, and no one actually *does* it. The manufacturer recommendation on my car is 10,000 miles.

Comment: @Snowman: that's a valid assumption but you're not correct. Cars don't have any monitoring to know how clean the oil is, they make a guess based on how how many miles the manufacturer recommends between oil changes. (better hope your mechanic resets your oil timer too!) Usually more important factors can include how aggressive you drive, what kind of oil you use, and what kind of weather conditions you live in.

Comment: 3000mi (or 5000km) is the spec for older vehicles (<2007). 5000mi (or 8000km) is the manufacturer spec for newer vehicles in Ford of Canada, but they ship with a semi-synthetic oil from the factory. If you go back to regular crude oil you should get it changed slightly more often, if you go to a full synthetic you can get away with longer intervals. However, don't switch oils in an engine with >100k miles on it. The engine seals have broken in at that point and the shock of a new oil can cause leaks or tears in the seals.

Comment: Pete - my cars in the UK have all been 10000 miles or 7000 miles for oil changes. And my tires have been always been changed around 10000 miles as that's when they start to get towards the mark, or it's coming up for winter, so worth changing them anyway.

Comment: @caesay please tell me where I claimed oil monitoring systems "know how clean the oil is" because that is not what I said: I specifically stated "based on driving conditions." They look at the recommended interval, and adjust based on driving conditions that may make the oil wear out faster or slower than average. Even then, it is just a guess, and probably a conservative one at that.

Comment: Tyres lasting only 10k miles? If my tIres lasted less than about 40k I would think I had been ripped off. I had a set go 13 years and 50k.

Answer (score 5):

The idea of "tyre rotating" is to spread or average out the wear and tear on the tyres, across all the tyres. The wear and tear comes down to several things, misalignment, suspension types (beam vs. coil) etc., and the driven vs's free rolling wheels, and the load distribution between them. Basically the idea is to get all the tyres wearing more or less evenly, so replacement can be made, all at the same time, without say the two front tyres being fully worn, and the rear tyres being 2/3rds worn...

That being said IF your tyres are near the end of their service life, and are all more or less evenly worn then don't bother, but if the front and back sets, have more than a marginal amount of difference in the thread depth, say 2mm on the front driven wheels and 4mm on the rear, then rotate them.

And keep your tyres inflated to the specification on the tyre, as some times the car manufacturers specify a lower pressure for ride comfort - as a cheap suspension boost.

Comment: With only 4 mm of tread, you would go off the road the first time it rains heavily. It should take years to wear down to that point.

Answer (score 4):

As a UK driver.
In 40 years and over a million miles, I have never rotated my tyres.  Never seen a recommendation to do so, either.
Maybe because I have never had a brand new car and never used a main dealer for servicing.
I suspect it is dealer culture, to make you think they are looking after you and add a little something(!) to the bill.

Comment: I too have been driving in the UK for over 40 years and my experience is the opposite.  No dealer has ever recommended rotating tyres to me or anyone I know.  It is the diy guides that recommend it.

Comment: The plural of "anecdote" is not "data."

Answer (score 3):

> Is planning a regular rotation of new tyres over their lifespan a good or bad plan?

It is not advisable, instead put the better tires on the back, for safety reasons.

[This is what understeer vs. oversteer means in real life:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSz7cm6MwH0)

[This is what happens with your car when the rear tire explodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHYt6KC5ZYc)

[This is what happens if your front tire explodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VltMWFlQMzI)

Now if you are a trained racing driver, and you always sit behind the steering wheel 100% concentrated, hands at 3 and 9 position, you can have fun with a little oversteer. For all others, best tire goes to the back!

You know, you can change tires by 2´s? So you won´t actually save anything by swapping!

Comment: Surely the point in regularly rotating tyres is so that you do not develop a "good" pair?  I've done a season in stock hatch and have undertaken MSA rally driver training but prefer 10 and 2.  I am well aware of what understeer is and I've experienced rapid tyre deflation on the front and rear of a vehicle at various times.  I have to say that rear was preferable as it was way easier to get the car back under control.

Comment: so much this, and the "rudder" answer above. These videos demonstrate what *most* drivers would experience and hence why best tires go on the rear. Made that mistake when I was younger and had my backend swing out on a highway when it snowed. Never made that mistake again.

Comment: I myself had a front tire pop on the German autobahn at ~130 km/h was pretty unexciting. Fortunately never had the same experience with a rear!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. I've seen user/service manuals state vastly different mileages for rotations.

For Subaru (and likely many AWD vehicles), they recommend every oil change (5,000 - 7,500 miles or so)

For other cars it's every 15,000 miles.

The justification for AWD being that the tires all need to be within 1/4" or so of tread so that the center differential is not overworked.

Comment: Nick - for my last 5 Subarus, the oil change was 10000 miles, except for my Litchfield which was 7000.

Comment: @RoryAlsop My 2014 WRX specified 7,500, probably because it was turbocharged/performance oriented.

Comment: I have a Subaru, but cheap shops skip rotation because they are so stuck on the "best to rear" thing. So with that idea, they would *never* rotate my tires, even if it leads to damage to the car. Stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note on their contradiction here:

> ... For improved handling and stability it is now recommended that the ‘best’
>   tyres should always be fitted at the rear of the vehicle. This is
>   irrespective of whether the car is front or rear wheel drive.

So if you do a few burnouts and your back tires are more worn than your front, according to their recommendation you are to put the better ones on the back (or in other words rotate your tires).

That contradiction aside, it's far more dangerous to lose a tire which is part of the steering system. I would want better on the front - if I were force to choose.

I believe they are assuming that someone will not rotate their tires for three years, then move the bald tires which were on the front, onto the back and drive for another three years.

If rotation  is done regular how can it possibly be bad? even tread all around the vehicle must be the safest setup.

I see this is one of those things like using Nitrogen instead of Air to fill tires if you don't regularly maintain.

Comment: "far more dangerous to lose a tire which is part of the steering system" — absolutely wrong!  what must one do if you lose a front tire?  floor it right off, to regain the control.  what would you do if your rear one is gone?!  @Harper describes it perfectly above.

Comment: I really think the point is being missed... IF you rotate the tires frequently, then the difference in tread wear is so small that there is almost no different between the front and back. IF you leave your tires un-rotated for 2 years the front wears down and becomes dangerous for: under-stear in bad conditions, increased front blow out potential, decreased braking potential. One should not be choosing best in back/front. They should be choosing to have all the tires as equal as possible to all round increased safty - not just the rare blowout condition.

Comment: The point is being missed, indeed.  There's a lot of disagreement of whether it's the front or the rear that has to have the best tyres.  The consensus amongst the folks that actually know the maths behind the situation, versus the guesswork, is to have the best tyres always on the rear.  Anyone who's claiming otherwise is simply doing it through guesswork.

Comment: Okay I am always interested in learning. Answer me this one question @ cnst. If your answer makes sense based on "knowing the maths" I'll delete my answer as I do not want to give miss information. The question: If math proves that there should always be more tread on the back than the front, then why arn't cars sold stock from factory, according to spec/math, with more tread on the back? Answer logically ill give you kudos, remove my wrong answer. Cannot answer logically, ill maintain that best configuration is equally good treat on all 4 tires, which requires rotation to *maintain* <- The pt

Comment: You're having a strawman argument now.  Noone said that the rear has to have more thread, just that it should not have more wear than the front.

Comment: Good and how do you prevent more wear in the front than the back? Regarding strawman argument: yes, you are focusing on back versus front whilst I am focusing on equilibrium (as I point out in my answer) which is my argument *for* regular rotation . Instead my answer is being dissected based on my preference for oversteer over understeer, which is different for each driver/experience. Both my vehicles I rotate every couple of months, I use a depth gauge in the center tread and keep my tires within 1mm of each other. I don't just rotate blind. I do not face back v front issue - I rotate.

Answer (score 1):

A main source for this kind of information should be the owner's manual. Every vehicle I have owned, the manual had a tyre rotation schedule.

Besides that fact, it is claimed that poor rear tyres are more dangerous because of the risk of losing the back end. I'm sure that's true for Formula 1 cars (and it used to be the case that they used much bigger tyres in that back many years ago, though it's not the case anymore), but I don't think a passenger vehicle doing anything remotely normal is at risk of this; in regular driving, more benefit will come from better steering and breaking. As a source for this, since many years ago I live at a place where we have snow/ice for 6 months a year, and I have yet to see a FWD vehicle lose the rear in any kind of situation.

Comment: The only vehicle I've ever had that didn't recommend tire rotation was one that you simply couldn't - a BMW with winter tires on it. The front and rear tires were different widths, and the special treads of the winter tires only worked at maximum efficiency when rotating in one direction. All four tires were mounted different. You could swap front-front and rear-rear, but only if you wanted to unmount the tires from the wheels and rebalance them every time.

Answer (score 1):

Each wheel location on the car will create its own unique wear pattern on its tyre. Rotating tyres between these positions causes a period of a few hundred miles in which the tyres are not worn to shape for that position. 
Since the optimum grip occurs when the tyre is worn to shape for its location, rotating the tyres introduces a sub-optimal grip for a few hundred miles.

Answer (score 1):

Some empirical evidence I have is that rear tire blowout is no issue at all.

One show I watched a few years ago simulated front tire blowout on a turn with 130kmph. The driver said that the car wanted to throw him in one direction but he firmly held the steering wheel and things were ok. I guess it also depends on driver concentration and reactions.

I've been in situations where rear tires have been slipping in very slippery road conditions. I was driving slowly so I could recover. Car was AWD but behaved like a rear wheel drive so I couldn't use acceleration to help myself (I've experimented with that, just balance was more to the rear wheels).

I personally prefer to have even wearing so I am rotating tires. Every year I change tires twice — for winter and summer conditions. So it is easy to do. Just tires need to be labeled after removing.

For some reason my tires don't wear much BTW. I don't think I'm a very  calm driver. But for some reason my thread depth doesn't go down quickly.

I wonder what causes most wear.

Answer (score 0):

I've never rotated my tires on a regular basis.

Usually, I buy new tires two at a time, put them on the front wheels, move the front tires to the back, and discard the (much worn) rear tires.  That's all the rotation I do.  If someone argues with me about that, I just shut them down with the tires rotate as you drive.

Putting your best tires in front is important -- a blowout in front is very dangerous, as you can lose control over steering.

The exception is when all four tires are in the same condition (like when I've just bought a vehicle).  Then, I wait until I need to replace them, and buy two high-quality tires for the front and two cheaper tires for the back.  Then when the back tires are worn, I use the plan described above.

Comment: and hopefully you wont one day learn the hard way what snap oversteer means...

Comment: Even more reason to have your best tires in front -- if the rear tires aren't grabbing the road any more, you need to have front tires that can.

Comment: Surely you're not equating "tires rotate as you drive" with the concept of tire rotation as presented in the question... I think I have an idea of what shuts people down when you bring that up.

Comment: @Jamie M: yes, saying "the tires rotate as you drive" is nonsensical.  Just enough so that the other person doesn't bother me any more.

Comment: @JamieM Saying "the tires rotate as you drive" is the troll's answer.  It's technically correct, but not in a useful way, and will cause the other party to facepalm and walk away shaking their head.  Which was OP's intention all along.

Comment: @Phil - yes, that was my intention.  But it's not a troll; it's more of a shut uppa you face.

Answer (score 0):

Given that

- ‘best’ tyres should always be fitted at the rear of the vehicle.

And

- In the UK most cars are front wheel drive, and therefore the front tyres wear quickest

I see no point in rotating tyres other than when replacing tyres, so the new tyres always go on the back.

**I suspect in the USA there are a lot more cars without front wheel drive....**

Comment: Many of the reasons the Kwik Fit article give for not rotating tyres would apply to tyres removed from the rear and fitted to the front when fitting a new pair on the rear though.

Comment: That would be a false assumption. May FWD drive vehicles all over north america. See the answer by Daniel for more context.